# test of number separated by a special character in extjs 4

Tags: extjs

I have The field named : percentOFuse

The type of "percentOFuse"  is FLOAT

I want to add a test before entered a data in this field , so we should entered only a number and we can entered a number separated by .

I try with this code :

```
xtype: 'numberfield',
fieldLabel: 'test',
id: 'percentOFuse',
flex: 1,
margin: '5 5 5 5'
```

but this code does not treat the case of a number separated by "."

unsuccessfully I try with

```
xtype: 'numberfield',
fieldLabel: 'test',
id: 'percentOFuse',
flex: 1,
margin: '5 5 5 5',
decimalPrecision="10",
decimalSeparator="."
```

Answer (score 0):

The default settings should allow you to enter in a decimal such as 1.2352

decimalSeparator is '.' by default and allowDecimal is true by default.  decimalPrecision is set to '2' by default.

Your code has:

```
decimalPrecision="10",
decimalSeparator="."
```

This should be:

```
 decimalPrecision: 10,
 decimalSeparator: "." // Note: add a , if more config below
```

I was able to just declare the number field as the following and get it to accept 123.456:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'numberfield',
        anchor: '100%',
        fieldLabel: 'Decimal',
        decimalPrecision: 10      
    }]
});
```

Here is fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/L9HAG/